# Haskell alternative to long list of pattern matches?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a function that outputs a booleanlike property given a datatype. This function calculates the property by pattern matching on the first constructor of the datatype, so something like

```
data C = C1 | C2 | .. | Cn 

f :: C -> Bool 
f (C1 _ _ ... _) = True
f (C2 _ _ ... _) = True
f (C3 _ _ ... _) = False
.
.
.
f (Cn _ _ ..._) = False
```

Is there a more compact way to perform pattern-matching, or is there another (also more compact) way to go about my property checking? I prefer not to add the property to the data type definition since it can be calculated with relative ease.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid the wildcard patterns using record syntax. Also, use a `case` expression to avoid having to repeat the function name, e.g.

```
f :: C -> Bool
f x = case x of
  C1 {} -> True
  C2 {} -> False
  ...
  Cn {} -> False
```

That's about as compact as it's going to get without changing your data type.

Comment: I will use this. Changing my datatype will result in more loss of aesthetics elsewhere. I didn't know about the record syntax now, and will be reading up on that next. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could turn each of the `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, etc into _functions_ which build some other datatype which has a structure that's easier to operate on...

Answer (score 6):

In addition, just list the `True`ones or the `False` ones, depending on what you have less, and make the majority outcome a default:

```
f C1{} = True
f C42{} = True
f _ = False                 -- all others false
```

Comment: Good idea, too bad the property is evenly divided. I have formatted the datatype definition for another use aswell, else I could've defined the data type in a way that could make f make fancy use of the Enum-class

Comment: @Haxelaar You still save at least 50% of the clauses if it is evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [`toConstr` in the `Data.Data`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-Data.html#t%3aConstr) module. This can give you a representation of the constructor, which you can then analyze as you wish (i.e. convert to a `String`, or get an index out of).

Answer (score 1):

Building on @yatima's answer, you could do something like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Char
import Data.Data

data C = C1 Int
       | C2 Int
       | C3 Int
       | C4 Int
       deriving (Data,Typeable)

f :: C -> Bool
f c = let [_,n] = show (toConstr c) in digitToInt n < 3
```

Then in GHCI

```
>> f (C1 0)
True
>> f (C2 0)
True
>> f (C3 0)
False
>> f (C4 0)
False
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps:

```
f (x _ _ ... _) = g x where
  g C1 = True
  g C2 = True
  g C3 = False
  .
  .
  .
  g Cn = False
```

You might be able to save a bit of typing using a case statement instead, but not much.

If we had more detail of the problem you were trying to solve (e.g. is there another representation for your data is there some pattern to the output) perhaps there's another approach.

Comment: This isn't going to work, as `(x _ ...)` is not a valid pattern - unless there are no underscores, in which case this way of doing things doesn't gain you anything!

Comment: @yatima2975 I'm guessing Clinton assumed `data C = C1 | C2 | .. | Cn` was fairly literal, and that the `_` were multiple arguments, whereas the type signature for `f` indicates otherwise.

Comment: @AndrewC: That makes sense, but then the parentheses are wrong, or the comma's in the tuple are missing :-).

Comment: @yatima2975 Indeed. I agree with you, since what I suggested doesn't make sense either. What I meant to say was that it's not entirely Clinton's fault since the code in the question is inconsistent.

Comment: @AndrewC: Yes, I've just blindly followed the question syntax. But hopefully the intent was clear anyhow.